# Registered Agent for Service of Process for California Corporations?

Tags: california, corporate-law, civil-procedure

May a California Corporation, such as S Corp or C Corp have its Registered Agent located outside California ? Please provide a cite.

Answer (score 2):

No, an individual who is designated as the "resident" agent must be a legal resident of the state. That's the whole point. Cal. Corp. Code. § 1502. If a corporation is designated as the resident agent, it must qualify under § 1505, including certifying the names and street address (within California) of the office of those authorized to accept legal process in the corporate name.